# Yes/No Checkbox change

Tags: checkbox

I have a Yes/No field in my database.  When I create a report it just give me a blank block.  Which is correct, however I want to have a Yes and No writing in the place of the checkbox.  How can I do this please.

Comment: Post some code from your project

Comment: That is the problem.  I have no code.  Just a checkbox